# Facing Error: File attachments aren’t supported for this bot for MS Teams Bot built using Bot Framework SDK

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, attachment, azure-bot-service

I have created an MS Teams bot using Node.js Bot Framework SDK and VS Studio Code's Teams Toolkit extension. The bot works perfectly fine when I test it locally using ngrok and Bot Framework Emulator. All the attachments are successfully sent to the users.
But when I deploy the bot on Azure and test on Teams Channel, it gives `Error: File attachments aren’t supported` error.

attachment.js

```
async function getInternetAttachment(filename, contentType, file_url) {

    // NOTE: The contentUrl must be HTTPS.
    return {
        name: "sample.mp4",
        contentType: "video/mp4,
        contentUrl: "" // Content url
    };
}
```

I use the same code for sending image files that executes without any errors, but when sending video or pdf files it gives the mentioned error.
Any help or advice is appreciated!

[image: Azure Channel Logs]
[image]

Comment: The BotFramework-Sample '56.teams-file-upload' successfully implements the functionality you are trying to achieve. Reference this [code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/56.teams-file-upload/bots/teamsFileUploadBot.js#L58) to compare for any differences. Also, the Teams manifest includes `supportsFiles: true` which you'll want to have included (ref code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/56.teams-file-upload/teamsAppManifest/manifest.json#L32)). Check these and try, again.

Comment: @StevenKanberg Thank you so much for your reply, I added the supportsFiles key in manifest but it didn't work, and I am trying to fetch the attachments URLs from airtable and send it to MS Teams, so inline method didn't work for me.

Comment: Any other way I can send video files using Bot Framework SDK (node.js)?

Comment: @DummyCron - Please refer below documentation for all supported scenarios:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/bots-filesv4#use-the-graph-apis

Answer (score 0):

We can solve the issue using three different scenarios.

- Cards
- Handling attachments
- Suggestions

Based on the requirement we can use the **Handling attachments** operation for the attachment's implementation. Use the code block below where we will attach the **attachment object** to handle the data which is being uploaded. This code block can be tested in **emulators.**

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    var msg = session.message;
    if (msg.attachments && msg.attachments.length > 0) {
     // Echo back attachment
     var attachment = msg.attachments[0];
        session.send({
            text: "You sent:",
            attachments: [
                {
                    contentType: attachment.contentType,
                    contentUrl: attachment.contentUrl,
                    name: attachment.name
                }
            ]
        });
    } else {
        // Echo back users text
        session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
    }
});
```

The **contentType** and **contentURL** will help to determine the attachment operation. The objection type and URL has to be defined within the **session.**

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried your code but I didn't work. If I use botbuilder latest version I get error: builder.ChatConnector is not a constructor. If I downgrade the version, the error is TypeError:class TeamsBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {    Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null